# What is the grok pattern for this custom log line?

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

21-09-2022 15:37:52.781 INFO  - Destination IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 | Source System IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8 | BrowserName:Edge(Chromium) | BrowserVersion:105 | requestURI:/home | Feature name:RUAMBOT | UserId:rohan | ApiCalled:/ruambot/api/getAllApplicationsByUserID() | ApiStatus:Success | Login Time:21-09-2022 15:37:51

Answer (score 0):

Here is the grok pattern for the mentioned log line:

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \- %{DATA:data}\:%{IP:destination_ip} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{IP:source_ip} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{DATA:browser_name} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{INT:browser_version} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{URIPATH:uri} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{DATA:feature_name}\| %{DATA:data}\:%{USERNAME:userid} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{URIPATH:api_call} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{DATA:api_status} \| %{DATA:data}\:%{DATESTAMP:login_time}
```

I have used the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to created the grok pattern.

Also, you can make use of the [Drop Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) of the logstash to drop the field `data` generated [see the output screenshot below] after parsing your logs using the above GROK pattern.

Output:
[image]
[image]